# How to Print the values obtained in a table after self joining two table in 'php'?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how to print A.station_id from given code

```
$query="SELECT A.train_no, A.station_id, A.arrival, A.dept, B.station_id, B.arrival, B.dept FROM TIME A,TIME B WHERE A.train_no = B.train_no AND A.station_id ='KNR' AND B.station_id='CLT' ";


$rs=mysql_query($query); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

echo "</td><td>".$row['A.station_id']."</td> <td>"       .$row['A.arrival'] ."</td> <td>".$row['A.dept'] . "</td><td>".$row['B.station_id'] . "</td> <td>".$row['B.arrival'] ."</td><td>" .$row['B.dept']. "</td><td>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look into the structure of the array you get back when you retrieve the data from the database. This helps to address single elements in there. Your code looks like you just tried blindly without checking and without consulting any examples...

Most likely you are looking for something like this (note that this code does NOT work as shown because of the issues mentioned below). It is just meant to point you into the right direction.

```
$query="SELECT A.train_no, A.station_id, A.arrival, A.dept, 
               B.station_id, B.arrival, B.dept 
        FROM TIME A,TIME B 
        WHERE A.train_no = B.train_no 
          AND A.station_id = 'KNR' 
          AND B.station_id = 'CLT' ";

$rs=mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    echo sprintf("<td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td>\n",
                 $row['train_no'], $row['station_id'], $row['arrival'], $row['dept']);
    echo sprintf("<td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td> <td>%s</td>\n", 
                 $row['station_id'], $row['arrival'], $row['dept']);
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

As correctly stated by Athul Raj in his answer you have a problem in your query itself. You should first run the query using a manual (interactive) database client. This helps sorting out potential syntax or logical problems. And you can be sure that the query actually returns a result when used inside your code. That said: you do not do any error checking at all in your code. This is why you probably did not see that your query throws an error...

Apart from that: the old `mysql` extension in PHP has been deprecated long ago. The documentation clearly states that. Use the newer `mysqli` extension or `pdo` which both offer prepared statements.

Answer (score 3):

Most database APIs don't include the table name in the associative array keys. So you should just use $row['arrival'].

If your query is returning two arrival columns from different tables, you should give one or both of them a different alias, e.g.

SELECT a.arrival AS a_arrival, b.arrival AS b_arrival, ...
Then you can refer to them as $row['a_arrival'] and $row['b_arrival'].